# How to start a long running process in a separate thread

Tags: c#, sql, multithreading

ok here we go last part almost done! one error to go hmmmmm.
This is using the suggestion and is complaining about delegates i think.

```
using System;


    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        pictureBox2.Visible = false;    
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Task t = new Task(() => GetsalesFigures(accCollection.Text));

        t.Start();  
    }

    private void SetPictureBoxVisibility(bool IsVisible)
    {
        if (pictureBox2.InvokeRequired)
        {
            pictureBox2.Invoke(new Action<bool>(SetPictureBoxVisibility), new Object[] { IsVisible });
        }
        else
        {
            pictureBox2.Visible = IsVisible;
        }
    }

    private void SetCheckBoxValue(bool IsChecked)
    {
        if (checkBox1.InvokeRequired)
        {
            pictureBox2.Invoke(new Action<bool>(SetCheckBoxValue), new Object[] { IsChecked });
        }
        else
        {
            checkBox1.Checked = IsChecked;
        }
    }

    private void AddItem(string value)
    {
        if (accCollection.InvokeRequired)
        {
            accCollection.Invoke(new Action<string>(AddItem), new Object[] { value });
        }
        else
        {
            accCollection.Items.Add(value);
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AutofillAccounts();
    }


    private void GetsalesFigures(string Acct)
    {
        try
        {
            string myConn = "Server=af" +
                            "Database=sdfta;" +
                            "uid=busdf4;" +
                            "pwd=drsdft;" +
                            "Connect Tisdf=120;";

            string acct;// test using 1560
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(myConn);
            SqlCommand Pareto = new SqlCommand();
            BindingSource bindme = new BindingSource();
            SqlDataAdapter adapt1 = new SqlDataAdapter(Pareto);
            DataSet dataSet1 = new DataSet();
            DataTable table1 = new DataTable();

           //CREATE THE THREAD

            //acct = accCollection.Text;
            acct = Acct;

            string fromDate = this.dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
            string tooDate = this.dateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");

            Pareto.Connection = conn;
            Pareto.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            Pareto.CommandText = "dbo.GetSalesParetotemp";
            Pareto.CommandTimeout = 120;

            Pareto.Parameters.AddWithValue("@acct", acct);
            Pareto.Parameters.AddWithValue("@from", fromDate);
            Pareto.Parameters.AddWithValue("@too", tooDate);


            //pictureBox2.Visible = true;
            //checkBox1.Checked = true;
            SetCheckBoxValue(true);
            SetPictureBoxVisibility(true);

            adapt1.Fill(dataSet1, "Pareto");
            //checkBox1.Checked = false;
            //pictureBox2.Visible = false;
            SetCheckBoxValue(false);
            SetPictureBoxVisibility(true);

            this.dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
            this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dataSet1;
            this.dataGridView1.DataMember = "Pareto";

            dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns(
                DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells);

            SetPictureBoxVisibility(true);
            acct = Acct;

        }
        catch (Exception execc)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Whoops! Seems we couldnt connect to the server!"
                            + " information:\n\n" + execc.Message + execc.StackTrace,
                            "Fatal Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
        } 
    }

    private void AutofillAccounts()
    {
        //get customers list and fill combo box on form load.
        try
        {
            string myConn1 = "Server=sdf33;" +
                                "Database=sdft;" +
                                "uid=bdf4;" +
                                "pwd=ddft;" +
                                "Connect Timeout=6000;";
            SqlConnection conn1 = new SqlConnection(myConn1);
            conn1.Open();
            SqlCommand accountFill = new SqlCommand("SELECT keycode FROM dbo.Customer", conn1);

            SqlDataReader readacc = accountFill.ExecuteReader();

            while (readacc.Read())
            {
                AddItem(readacc.GetString(0).ToString());
            }
            conn1.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception exc1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Whoops! Seems we couldnt connect to the server!"
                            + " information:\n\n" + exc1.Message + exc1.StackTrace,
                            "Fatal Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
        }
    }
}
```

}

not sure where the changes should be made, shouldnt it be in the account method now?

Comment: You realize that you have two instances of Form1? 1) Application.Run(new Form1()); 2) in your Worker Function. Form1 form1 = new Form1(); - and I wouldn't post server ip's / user and passwords. But thats just me.

Comment: just noticed the id and ip(my bad). Yeh the app.run method ive never looked into (always auto gen), but as u can see in the getsales method in my program-class i need to call the forms controls, only way to do this is to create a new form.  i see this is why my program is doing nothing.  how do i call the forms controls inside my main class?

Comment: change Action<bool> to Action<string>. And then could you step-through debug and tell me where exactly the cross-thread reference happens?

Comment: stepped into it, its happens at "acct = accCollection.Text;" inside my get sales method. then it catchs the error.  has this anything to do with my main class?  i hear forms are by default already threads? or again is that overcomplicating things?

Comment: what kind of control is accCollection?

Comment: its a combo box, i fill the combo box with all the accounts from mhy database for the user to look through and select, this then gets passed into my other sql query that uses the value as a paramter to send to my query

Comment: sorry but ur coe has con fused me a little seems ur using my sales method again? shouldnt i be using the accounts one?  2 seconds ill upload what i have so far. ::UPDATED::

Comment: Please check my code exactly.  AutofillAccounts();  needs to be in your FORM_LOAD(); Task t = new Task(() => GetsalesFigures(accCollection.Text)); t.Start();  in your button_click. ....

Comment: ah i see, i was trying to create a new thread.  ok ive set it up like yours but its throwing the same exception but this time its throwing it when the task is created in button click, 

+  Thrown: "Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'accCollection' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on." (System.InvalidOperationException) Exception Message = "Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'accCollection' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.", Exception Type = "System.InvalidOperationException"

Comment: See my update. you need to put the text of your combo box in a temp string before launching the task.

Comment: yes its solved the problem!  runs the query too but is complaining about my datagridview!"Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'dataGridView1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on." (System.InvalidOperationException) Exception Message = "Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'dataGridView1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.", Exception Type = "System.InvalidOperationException"same thing which means a similar aproach is needed, why the hell is this control complaining? i dont see where its cross threading

Comment: As I said, each control being accessed by a cross thread operation must be encapsulated in a method just like the pictureBox. From here  on you should be able to do it. Good luck!

Comment: ah i see, derp! datagrid view is a from control, thats in the thread! thats why its complaining, so now i need to encaps it with a invoke?
that being said my other methods are simple bools and strings, but a datagrid is different, could u show me the datagrid version? last advice!

Comment: Exactly :) - there should be enough examples provided now though!

Comment: idd there enough to keep me going for the weekend now to have a rllllly good look into.  as i said though how does the datagride invoke work, its slightly different from checking a box and passing a string

Comment: Updated some more, see the `SetDataGrid(..)` method and its invocation at `GetsalesFigures`.

Comment: wow, its works.....it actually works!!!! this is both amazing and stupid at the same time, all this work for one picture xD, but mate i cant thankyou enough! upvote this guy!! if i ever meet u rounds are on me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed some minor spelling errors, didn't have a compiler at hand back then.
To your last error: Just provide the accCollection.Text as parameter to your method. See the updated button1_Click() and GetsalesFigures(String Acct).
This is how my Partial Class : Form looks like

```
  public Form1()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  pictureBox2.Visible = false;
}
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
  AutofillAccounts(); 
}  
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  checkBox1.Checked = true;
  string acct = accCollection.Text;
  Task t = new Task(() => GetsalesFigures(acct)); 
  t.Start();
}
private void GetsalesFigures(String Acct)
{
  // (...)
  //pictureBox2.Visible = true; use SetPictureBoxVisibility
  SetPictureBoxVisibility(true);
  //checkBox1.Checked = true; use SetCheckBoxValue
  SetCheckBoxValue(true);
  // (...)
  SetCheckBoxValue(false);
  SetPictureBoxVisibility(false); 
  // (...)
  acct = Acct;
 // (...)
 SetDataGrid(true, dataSet1, "Pareto", DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells);
}
private void AutofillAccounts()
{
   // (...)
   while (readacc.Read())             
    {                 
      AddItem(readacc.GetString(0).ToString());             
    }
}
private void SetCheckBoxValue(bool IsChecked)
{
  if (checkBox1.InvokeRequired)
  {
    pictureBox2.Invoke(new Action<bool>(SetCheckBoxValue), new Object[] { IsChecked });
  }
  else
  {
    checkBox1.Checked = IsChecked;
  }
}
private void SetPictureBoxVisibility(bool IsVisible)
{
  if (pictureBox2.InvokeRequired)
  {
    pictureBox2.Invoke(new Action<bool>(SetPictureBoxVisibility), new Object[] { IsVisible });
  }
  else
  {
    pictureBox2.Visible = IsVisible;
  }
}
// Your latest comment
 private void AddItem(string value)
 {
  if (accCollection.InvokeRequired)
  {
    accCollection.Invoke(new Action<string>(AddItem), new Object[] {   value });
  }
  else
  {
    accCollection.Items.Add(value);
  }
}
private void SetDataGrid(bool AutoGenerateColumns, Object DataSource, String DataMember, DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode Mode)
{
  if (this.dataGridView1.InvokeRequired)
  {
    this.dataGridView1.Invoke(new Action<bool, Object, String,   DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode>(SetDataGrid),
                              AutoGenerateColumns, DataSource, DataMember, Mode);
  }
  else
  {
    this.dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = AutoGenerateColumns;
    this.dataGridView1.DataSource = DataSource;
    this.dataGridView1.DataMember = DataMember;
    dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns(Mode);
  }
}
```

And Program.cs

```
 static class Program
{
/// <summary>
/// The main entry point for the application.
/// </summary>
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
  Application.EnableVisualStyles();
  Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
  Application.Run(new Form1());
}
```

To summary your problem: You have to encapsulate all control-related updates you want to call from another thread than the main thread just like I did it with the two controls.

Some ressources you might want to check for multithreading / tasks
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/06/30/9809774.aspx

Comment: i see, but where do i put the method in relation to my 2 classes? program and form1.

Comment: ah so im putting my sql getsales method back into my form class?????? i thought that was the original problem? hmmm ill give it a run and let you know! many thanks!

Comment: where am i putting the setpicture box method? is that inside my sales method?

Comment: thanks for this help, but unfortunatly i cant seem to get my head around what exactly is calling what, here what i have now.

Comment: as u can see theres 2 errors inside this new method, not entirly sure what it is that method is doing

Comment: ok its just one error now, 
pictureBox2.Invoke(new Action<bool>(SetPictureBoxVisibility, new Object[] {IsVisible}) expected a method name? any idea?

Comment: ah i see how it works now.....tbh its awesome took me a while to figure out, but ive a got a new problem that i was scared of might happen, when i click my button this happens! 
error:Thrown: "Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'accCollection' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on." (System.InvalidOperationException) Exception Message = "Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'accCollection' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.", Exception Type = "System.InvalidOperationException"

Comment: i think its something to do with forms.....forms are threads by default? or am i overthinking some easy fix? (i pray its an easy fix)

Comment: Just update your main post and I'll respond accordingly in my post. You'll have to do another method to add items to accCollection. Since this is also a control on the main form. Similar to SetCheckBoxValue()

Comment: ok ive put in the acc invoke method same thing again is happening, its asking for a method name,  where do i call this method,  Sorry for asking so much but my brain is soooo fried atm and i would love to get this working today so i have the weekend to then look through and fully understand the use of invoking etc. (also i owe you several pints if this works!)

Comment: Could you update the whole code you have so far in your first post? That would be easier for me to help.

Comment: sorry not method name, its this Error 1 No overload for 'AddItem' matches delegate 'System.Action<bool>' something about delegates? ive looked into delegates breifly, is this another simple thing im overthinking?

Comment: My bad, Action<string> instead of Action<bool>. Copy paste mistake.

Comment: ok error is gone, but same error from before when i run the button, cross thread error
"Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'accCollection' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on." (System.InvalidOperationException) Exception Message = "Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'accCollection' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.", Exception Type = "System.InvalidOperationException"

Comment: is it beacuse i need to add a new task? because this is getting called to a thread?

Comment: stepped into it, its happens at "acct = accCollection.Text;" inside my get sales method. then it catchs the error. has this anything to do with my main class? i hear forms are by default already threads? or again is that overcomplicating things?

Answer (score 2):

You have many problems in your code:

- The call to `Application.Run()` is a blocking call. It won't return until you close your form.
  So your thread starts when your application is about to exit.

  Just start your thread before calling Run():

  ```
  Thread aniSql = new Thread(new ThreadStart(getSalesFigures));
  aniSql.Start();
  Application.Run(new Form1());
  ```

  A Tip: Start using the debugger and step through your code. You would have noticed that your thread function is never reached.
- You create a second instance of Form1 in the function `GetSalesFigures`. You have to use the existing instance when polling the state of the checkbox.
- Your thread will perform only a single check and then it returns. You have to write some code in `GetSalesFigures` to wait for the user to check the checkbox. Otherwise nothing will happen.
  You can use a `ManualResetEvent` for waiting on an event:

  ```
  ManualResetEvent mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);

  void YourThreadFunc() {
      // Wait until someone signals mre
      mre.WaiteOne();
      // start sql
      ...
  }
  ```

  In your form:

  ```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      // trigger the WaitHandle to signal the waiting thread
      mre.Set();
  }
  ```

Comment: yeh i usually do use the debugger using breaks etc, but i heard when using threads its very difficult to use breaks.  is this true or can you still step through exactly how you would running normal code?

Comment: Of cause you can set breakpoints and do single stepping in a multithreaded applications.

Comment: excellent, ok i tryed running the thread before the app starts.  it runs the thread and sees that the button was not clicked so ignores the sql call.  when my form starts up and the button is clicked the thread seems to be doing nothing. does it run the thread method only once?

Comment: Yes the threads method is running only once. See my edits, you have a few more problems in your code

Comment: getSalesFigures is a dead method, i commented the code out because calling the sql from the form was ofc freezing it untill completion, so im moved it too the main class using it inside a thread