# WebBrowser control won't navigate to URL when the call is via a timer

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, timer, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to make an app in C# with integrated [System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). I need to implement some functionality that would make periodic checks for user activity and if the user is not active for some timespan, it will redirect the browser control back to the home page.

Below is a code snippet from my app. I am using the [System.Timers.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class to periodically call the `CheckUserActivity` method, which just computes the timespan and if the timespan is larger than some threshold, it should redirect the browser by calling the `goHome` method.

Unfortunately, this just won't work and the behaviour seems rather strange to me. I added some logging to see what actually happens (see below). The "Should go away soon" message shows up OK, but after that the browser doesn't naviagte to home page and the second message after the call to `Navigate` also doesn't show up.

**I get absolutely no errors. Everything works as expected except that the call to the webBrowser's `Navigate` method and the call after that just vanished somehow.**

I suspect that the problem might have something to do with threads, but I have very little experience with C# so I have absolutely no idea what the problem might be here.

I also tried to rewrite the code using the `System.Threading.Tasks.Task` library in the same way as mentioned at `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8267298/how-to-start-a-long-running-process-in-a-separate-thread` (sry for the link inside the code block - not enough reputation :D ). I put the checking code inside infinite loop that runs as the long running task and the thread sleeps for two seconds, but I ran into exactly the same problem.

Thanks very much for any advice. Here is my code snippet (it should work as a standalone project):

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="TimerTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="800" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <WebBrowser x:Name="webBrowser" 
                            LoadCompleted="webBrowser_LoadCompleted"
                ></WebBrowser>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**C#:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Timers;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace TimerTest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        private Uri URI_home;
        private Timer timer;
        private Uri URI_last;
        private DateTime lastUsed;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            URI_home = new Uri("http://example.com/", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
            URI_last = URI_home;

            InitializeComponent();

            webBrowser.Navigate(URI_home);

            // Create a timer with a two second interval.
            timer = new Timer(2000);
            // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer. 
            timer.Elapsed += CheckUserActivity;
            timer.AutoReset = true;
            timer.Enabled = false;
            lastUsed = DateTime.Now;
        }

        private void goHome()
        {
            //System.Windows.Forms.MethodInvoker update = delegate()
            //{
            webBrowser.Navigate(URI_home);
            //};
            //webBrowser.invoke(update);
        }

        private void logMessage(string msg)
        {
            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
            Console.WriteLine(now.ToString() + ": " + msg);
        }

        private void CheckUserActivity(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            logMessage("Entered CheckUserActivity handler");
            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
            TimeSpan timeSpan = now - lastUsed;
            logMessage("Timespan is " + timeSpan.Seconds.ToString());
            if (timeSpan.Seconds > 5 && URI_home != URI_last)
            {
                timer.Enabled = false;
                logMessage("Timer is now disabled.");
                logMessage("Will go away soon.");
                goHome();
                logMessage("Should have gone home");
            }
        }

        private void webBrowser_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            WebBrowser browser = (WebBrowser)sender;
            Uri URI_navigated = e.Uri;
            URI_last = URI_navigated;
            logMessage("WebBrowser LoadCompleted event triggered. LoadCompleted for URI (saved as URI_last): " + URI_navigated.AbsoluteUri);
            logMessage("Timer enabled status: " + timer.Enabled.ToString());
            lastUsed = DateTime.Now;
            timer.Enabled = true;
            logMessage("Timer is now enabled (end of LoadCompleted handler).");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the output of one session:

```
11.9.2014 8:10:01: WebBrowser LoadCompleted event triggered. LoadCompleted for URI (saved as URI_last): http://example.com/
11.9.2014 8:10:01: Timer enabled status: False
11.9.2014 8:10:01: Timer is now enabled (end of LoadCompleted handler).
11.9.2014 8:10:03: Entered CheckUserActivity handler
11.9.2014 8:10:03: Timespan is 2
11.9.2014 8:10:05: Entered CheckUserActivity handler
11.9.2014 8:10:05: Timespan is 4
11.9.2014 8:10:07: Entered CheckUserActivity handler
11.9.2014 8:10:07: Timespan is 6
11.9.2014 8:10:09: Entered CheckUserActivity handler
11.9.2014 8:10:09: Timespan is 8
11.9.2014 8:10:11: Entered CheckUserActivity handler
11.9.2014 8:10:11: Timespan is 10
11.9.2014 8:10:13: Entered CheckUserActivity handler
11.9.2014 8:10:13: Timespan is 12
11.9.2014 8:10:15: Entered CheckUserActivity handler
11.9.2014 8:10:15: Timespan is 14
11.9.2014 8:10:17: Entered CheckUserActivity handler
11.9.2014 8:10:17: Timespan is 16
11.9.2014 8:10:19: Entered CheckUserActivity handler
11.9.2014 8:10:19: Timespan is 18
11.9.2014 8:10:21: Entered CheckUserActivity handler
11.9.2014 8:10:21: Timespan is 20
11.9.2014 8:10:23: Entered CheckUserActivity handler
11.9.2014 8:10:23: Timespan is 22
11.9.2014 8:10:25: Entered CheckUserActivity handler
11.9.2014 8:10:25: Timespan is 24
11.9.2014 8:10:27: Entered CheckUserActivity handler
11.9.2014 8:10:27: Timespan is 26
11.9.2014 8:10:29: Entered CheckUserActivity handler
11.9.2014 8:10:29: Timespan is 28
11.9.2014 8:10:30: WebBrowser LoadCompleted event triggered. LoadCompleted for URI (saved as URI_last): http://www.iana.org/domains/reserved
11.9.2014 8:10:30: Timer enabled status: True
11.9.2014 8:10:30: Timer is now enabled (end of LoadCompleted handler).
11.9.2014 8:10:31: Entered CheckUserActivity handler
11.9.2014 8:10:31: Timespan is 1
11.9.2014 8:10:33: Entered CheckUserActivity handler
11.9.2014 8:10:33: Timespan is 3
11.9.2014 8:10:35: Entered CheckUserActivity handler
11.9.2014 8:10:35: Timespan is 5
11.9.2014 8:10:37: Entered CheckUserActivity handler
11.9.2014 8:10:37: Timespan is 7
11.9.2014 8:10:37: Timer is now disabled.
11.9.2014 8:10:37: Will go away soon.
```

The browser navigates to the homepage (example.com) after it is started. The timer is disabled, but gets enabled at the end of the `LoadCompleted` handler. The user lingers for a bit and then clicks a link on the page. `LoadCompleted` is triggered (timer remains enabled, because we didn't have to change URL yet). The user lingers again, but this time not on the homepage, the condition inside 
`CheckUserActivity` is true after a while, the timer is disabled and the browser should navigate back to home page, but nothing happens... Sad story :(

Comment: Have you got an exception about Thread or something ?

Comment: @T00rk No exceptions or errors at all.

Comment: Don't pile those calls up every 2 seconds blindly; trigger them only after the `DocumentCompleted` event!

Comment: @TaW can you elaborate on this, please

Comment: I suspect you never let it complete anything..like a user that keeps clicking a link and thereby blocks the whole browser..Start you timer in the `DocumentCompleted` event and stop it in the `Elasped` event. - ( Aside:For some scenarios there is a good reason to use 2 Timers, e.g. one to kepp things going and one to detect a timeout..)

Comment: @TaW OK, I did as you said. I enable the timer when the LoadCompleted event is triggered (I don't have DocumentCompleted - System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser doesn't have one) and I disable it when I enter the `if` statement inside the `CheckUserActivity` handler and again I get the first message box, but nothing happens after that.

Comment: Good ;-) As for solving your issues, I think it may be worth to comment out __all__ MessageBox calls and put in Console.WriteLines - MessageBoxes have a way of messing thing up sometimes. Create a Log function that outputs messages and a current time..

Comment: Is there a place where URI_Last gets set?

Comment: @TaW Thanks for trying to help :) I changed the tag to WPF. I also implemnted some logging to the console (see edited question). URI_last gets set inside the Navigated event handler.

Comment: Hm, I don't do WPF (yet) so here is my last idea: Looking up the [Docs at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.navigated%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) I see 'Navigated: Occurs when the document being navigated to is located and has started downloading. - This event will only be fired for top-level navigations.'.  Not sure if you should use it at all, since nothing is completed yet..

Comment: @TaW I'm pretty clueless here, too. I ditched the Navigated event completely (just using the LoadCompleted event), but still the same story. I should probably sleep on it, maybe tomorrow will be a better day for debugging :)

Comment: So, I made a separate project that deals only with the problem I have encountered and edited the question so that it reflects exactly what I am dealing with at the moment. Maybe someone will know what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a threading problem - if you replace the goHome method with the following one, it starts working.

Enjoy :)

```
private void goHome()
{
        Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => { webBrowser.Navigate(URI_home); });
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I had a hunch that it might have something to do with threads, because I encountered similar problems in Java, but I don't know how thread dispatching works in WPF so I wasn't exactly sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your timer event is not bound to the correct one.
Try that instead

```
timer.Tick += CheckUserActivity;
```

**Edit**

Maybe a problem of Thread access :

```
private void goHome()
{
    MethodInvoker update = delegate()
    {
        webBrowser.Navigate(URI_home);
    };
    webBrowser.invoke(update);        
}
```

Comment: I am using System.Timers.Timer, it doesn't have the Tick property.

Comment: He wrote that he is using a ` System.Timers.Timer` which doesn't have the usual `tick`! event!

Comment: Are you sure the event is fired ?

Comment: @T00rk Yes it is. I am seeing the first message box i put up, but not the one after the call to the browser's navigate method

Comment: When using this I get `'System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser' does not contain a definition for 'invoke' and no extension method 'invoke' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` during compilation...